# How To pass multiple object as a parameter from controller to service then in Api Service in angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am tried to Pass the multiple object as a parameter in method call from controller to service layer in angular ,but I was not being able to pass multiple object.(Single object  can be passed) can any one suggest me..

Code of Controller

```
clientService.getUsers($scope.firstobject,$scope.secondobject).then(function (data) {
            var model = data.Model;

 });
```

How we Retrieve the two object in service layer in angular and then pass this two  object Web API service Controller.

Code Of Service in angular

```
getUsers: function (firstobject,secondobject) {
            return $http.post('/api/clientLogic/SaveClient/' + firstobject +secondobject)
                .then(function (response) {
                    return response.data;
                });
        },
```

Comment: Why are you adding the objects to the URL ?

The $http.post request works in the next way : 

$http.post('/someUrl', { yourfirstobject : firstobject , yoursecondobject: secondobject})

Comment: can you please suggest me ,how I can achieve this functionality as single object is passed but We cannot collect multiple object in service layer.

Comment: If you want to merge the objects you can use [https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend ] (angular.extend) , after that you can add it as parameter in your $http.post function

Comment: No, I don't want to merge the Object or Array ,I just want to pass from controller to service layer and then in web API. and in web API there are two enumerable type of parameter in function.

Comment: @eusoj - want one more help as how I did Routing in Web API  for two parameter in function.

Comment: May you give us a hint, how your web service expects the data to arrive and what kind of data you are storing in `firstobject` and `secondobject`? Also why is the solution suggested by @eusoj not working for you?

Comment: @eusoj answer is working for me in angular level but what I do in Service Layer web API ,,Route for Method which we define , Can you please suggest the route for method having two  object type parameter for that method.  ...[Route("SaveClientAttributeValues/{firstboject}/{secondobject}")]

Comment: It's invalid send the object in this form , I don't understand why you want it in the URL , a POST request is better in this situation

Comment: @eusoj firstly thanks for your response ,so how I Collect the Parameter object In web API ,without writing route definition above the method , can you please tell me because I tried normally , writing just simple method which having two parameter but unable to call that method from angular service.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the $http.post in this way

```
    $http.post('/someUrl', 
            { yourfirstobject : firstobject , 
                yoursecondobject: secondobject
            }).then( 
                function( response){
            });
```

But if you are using a service you can do somethink like that:

```
    'use strict';

    var myService = angular.module('clientService', ['ngResource']);

    myService.factory('clientService', function clientService($resource){
      var rsc = $resource('/someUrl' , {} , {});
      return rsc;
    });
```

With that in your controller you can do :

```
    object = angular.extend ( {} , firstobject, secondobject);
    clientService.save( object );
```

I have a simple CRUD example in this [Github Repository](https://github.com/blacknash/angularjspuebla/tree/master/playground/crud/js)